# Braintree / Javascript: how to get transaction data (card and address) to prefill for customers with previous transactions?

Tags: javascript, braintree

I am using Braintree's Hosted Fields and Javascript.  I am successfully able to do a successful signup and sending a payment nonce however I am unable to figure out how to have a user who already has a subscription in the Braintree portal to show up with their information preloaded in the Braintree Hosted Fields already (address, part of credit card, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The only address field in Hosted Fields is the postal code. You may need to build a custom form to populate the additional address values.

You can grab Vault data from your server using a [payment method lookup](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/find/). Then you can prefill the data in Hosted Fields.

Here is an example that shows how to use prefilled values for the expiration date:

```
var storedCreditCardInformation = {   
  // get this info from your server with a payment method lookup   
  month: '09',   
  year: '2017' 
}; 

braintree.hostedFields.create({   
  client: clientInstance,   
  fields: {     
    expirationMonth: {       
      selector: '#expiration-month',       
      prefill: storedCreditCardInformation.month     
    },     
    expirationYear: {       
      selector: '#expiration-year',       
      prefill: storedCreditCardInformation.year     
    }   
  } 
}, 
callback);
```

Full Disclosure: I work at Braintree. For additional questions, please feel free to contact Braintree Support support@getbraintree.com.

Comment: Does the same apply when using Drop-in UI?

Comment: Yes - The documentation on the Drop-In can be found [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/overview/javascript/v3). 

Some of the features are: 
   Allow customers to delete saved payment methods
   Collect information included on the payment form:
     -Credit card number
     -Expiration date
     -Postal code and CVV (when AVS and CVV rules are enabled)

Documentation on PaymentMethod.update() can be found [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-methods/ruby#update).

Comment: Hey @turaco .  I have a JS braintree v3 client and was given a backend api to update the paymentMethod.  It takes a bearer token and if successful, it returns a nonce.  
What exactly am I do with this nonce to update the payment info?  I'm not really sure where to be calling this.

Comment: @Anthony I'm answering your question [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53167396/javascript-how-to-use-braintree-paymentmethod-nonce-bu)