# JavaScript: how to use Braintree paymentMethod nonce bu

Tags: javascript, braintree

I am using Braintree v3 for a client implementation. I am using the dropin UI. 
I am trying to create a new vaulted card. I have an api from the backend team I’m working with to update payment method. It takes a user token in the Header and if successful, the response is a payment method nonce.

I’m just not sure what to do with this paymentMethod nonce or where to actually call the api.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I work for Braintree. If you need a more detailed answer, please don't hesitate to reach out to* [Braintree Support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact)

The flow should be as follows:

- the server generates client token and sends it to the client
- the client obtains customer payment method and then a `payment_method_nonce` and sends it to your server
- the server receives the nonce
- a transaction is [created using the nonce](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale)

The Drop-in will display a customer's saved payment methods and automatically add any newly-entered payment methods to their Vault record [if you pass a customer_id when generating a client token.](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/customization/javascript/v3#display-a-saved-payment-method)

Here is the documentation on how to [vault an updated payment method.](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update)

Comment: thanks @turaco.  Will vaulted cards show up as options for a user if they come back to re-subscribe (assuming the clientToken was created with a customer_id) ?
I am trying to populate the fields of the form with the user's last user card data / billing info.

Comment: @Anthony: the vaulted cards will show up in the Drop-In as payment options that the customer can choose. See an example [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/customization#display-a-saved-payment-method)